# Check if user is authenticated outside laravel (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a secure autologin script and i would like to add an extra layer of security besides an md5 hash.

I am using laravel for my main application, and from here i will try to autologin an allready authenticated user to a wordpress blog. How can i check the session or cookie if the user is authenticated with the laravel app within the wordpress plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: md5 has nothing to do with security

Comment: Check out this answer [http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=70490#p70490](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=70490#p70490)